# header location php why when no white space

Tags: php, mysql

why on earth wont this work their is no spaces no outputs but yet i put redirect just in before configuartion .php which just holds my db connections what gives

```
 <?php 
   require('configuration.php');
   $voucher = $_SESSION['voucher'] ;
   $result = mysql_query("SELECT used FROM codes where code='".$voucher."'");
   $row =mysql_fetch_row($result);
   if ( $row['used']  == "1" ) {
       header('Location: invalid.php');
       exit;
   }
   if ( $row['used']  == "0" ) { 
       header('Location: valid.php');
       exit;
   }
?>
```

Comment: **WARNING** your code may be suseptible to sql injection attacks.

Comment: What is the content of `configuration.php` ?

Comment: NOTE also that (as far as I know) blank space after the final php tag `?>` COUNTS as output. So when checking `configuration.php` check that as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chances are `configuration.php` has something being output. (Remember that require/include output anything at that point in time, so any white-space or characters would also be output at that time).

out of curiosity, if you do the following does it work:

```
<?php
  ob_start();
  require('configuration.php');

  // your code with header(...);

  ob_end_flush();
```

If it works with the `ob_start`/`ob_end_flush` calls in place, `configuration.php` is outputting something. However, some things to note:

- Never send data coming in from a client (via `$_GET`/`$_POST`/`$_SESSION`) directly to SQL. Even though you may be setting the session data, depending where it comes from (cookie for example) it's very easy to start poking around your database.
- `Location` should be a fully-qualified path (`http://mydomain.com/myfile.php` not just `myfile.php`)

Answer (score 1):

Your code only considers if $row['used'] is 0 or 1. Not if it doesn't exist at all. Can you var_dump $row to see what you get?